# Option Menu does not appear in Android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

I have this code to create the menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.tip_menu, menu);
    return true;

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MNU_PREV:
        animateTextViewsPrev();
        break;

    case MNU_NEXT:
        animateTextViewsNext();
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:id="@+id/prev_tip" android:title="@string/prevTip"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/next_tip" android:title="@string/nextTip"></item>
    </menu>
```

In a smartphone with Android 2.1 the menu is visible but in other mobile whit 4.1.1 is invisible.
Somebody now how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is you target Android, good to know, in android 4.0 them has redesign the menu layout.

I think you is missing `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` in the call `onCreateOptionsMenu`

In my code I has,

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The min minSdkVersion is 7 and the targetSdkVersion is 15, is for Android 2.1 , i have the call to super but I forgot paste it.

Comment: Yes my code is this: `code`public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}`/code`

Comment: What is happen if you edit the targetSdkVersion to 7 and then run the app on you phone that has android 4.1.1

Comment: Can you has a event listener that prevent `onCreateOptionsMenu`event? Do you know if the methods `onCreateOptionsMenu` is call for you in android 4.1.1? Also try to create a new XML files, can be some hidden error in this?

Comment: Yes, was that, i solve it, i have a gesture listener to implement swype gesture and a touch listener, and when i comment the code the menu appears, It was the touch listener, A lot of Thanks FIG-GHD742

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with the same problem.. read some queries and documentation.. Hope this might help you.

Here's my XML file for a menu..

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_send_feedback"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_send_feedback"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_share_app"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_share_app"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_rate_app"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_rate_app"/>
```

JAVA Code goes here..

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

For android phones which have option button (at the bottom of the phone) the menu item which are showAsAction="never" comes when the button is pressed.. or else they will be shown normally on the action bar options menu..

Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Comment: THX for "For android phones which have option button (at the bottom of the phone) the menu item which are showAsAction="never" comes when the button is pressed.. or else they will be shown normally on the action bar options menu.."

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the "targetSdkVersion" to **10** in manifest file

Answer (score -4):

It needs the ID in the java! :)